# How to reuse local file.js in several vue projects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

My file.js has some functions that I would like to reuse in several vue projects, specifically within App.vue

the file structure is:

```
-- projec1
---- src
------ App.vue

-- project2
---- src
------ App.vue

-- myfile.js
```

I can't import it directly like that

```
import * as alias from '../../myfile.js'
```

because the file path is not found during the production build

```
ERROR Failed to compile with 1 error3: 21: 38 PM
This relative module was not found: ../../myfile.js
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Something in package.json like

```
{
    myLocalDependency: path/to/myFile.js
}
```

and in App.vue to be able to do

```
<script>
import myLocalDependency from '...'

export default {
     mounted: {
         myLocalDependency.myPreciousFunction()
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your file.js is not very complicated you can use [Adding Instance Properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) to your Vue.js application. for example in your `main.js` file you should do something like this:

```
function converter(){}
Vue.prototype.$converter = converter();
```

And then you can use it anywhere in your vue project just like `this.$converter`